# How to show selected shape in the center of Visio Web Access Webpart

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, shapes, visio

How to show selected shape in the center of Visio Web Access Webpart and set the scale of this shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:

```
var vwaPage = vwaControl.getActivePage(); 
vwaPage.centerViewOnShape(shape.getId());
```